# Django: relations between two objects of the same model

Tags: django, postgresql, relation

I have created this model:

```
class Process(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Process name', max_length=50, unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, max_length=50, null=True, verbose_name='Process owner')
```

I want to create multiple processes and from those build a hierarchy. Here is a hierarchy model:

```
class Hierarchy(models.Model):
    mainprocess = models.ForeignKey(Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='mainprocess', verbose_name='Main process name')
    subprocess = models.ForeignKey(Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='subprocess', verbose_name='Sub process name')
    order = models.IntegerField('Process order', default=1)
```

EDIT: Got it work with code above and now I can build some type of hierarchy, but there are some issues:

- I would like to restrict so that subprocess can be under only one main process. If i create a two different hierarchies with same subprocess it gives an unique contrstraint violation on the subprocess id, so I guess it works now.
- I would like to restrict so that main process and sub process cannot be same. Now I can create it, but is there a way to do this in the model itself or do I restrict this on the client side when hierarchy is created?

What would be the right way to build this type of model/hierarchy? This might be very basic issue, but I couldn't find any related issues to apply a solution from, so any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: what i want to accomplish with the hierarchy model is to keep track on the process tree like for example:

```
1 Process (main process)
    1.1 process (sub process)
        1.1.1 process (sub process)
    1.2 process (sub process)
        1.2.1 process (sub process)

2 Process (main process)
    2.1 process (sub process)
    2.2 process (sub process)

n Process (main process)
    n.1 process (sub process)
        n.1.1 process (sub process)
            n.1.1.1 process (sub process)
    n.2 process (sub process)
```

Comment: Please could you explain what is the purpose of hierarchy model

Comment: My idea was that this would help me built some type of process tree with it and keep track of where each process in located in the three (thats why there is the order field). See an example in the original post.